# Did Japan make a contribution to World War II way out of proportion to its nominal relative GDP?

Tags: world-war-two, military, economy, japan

I was surprised to read these [1938 figures](http://historum.com/blogs/guaporense/994-economics-world-war-two.html) (admittedly estimates) of 1938 GDP for the major combatants of World War II.

In round figures, the U.S. had  $85 billion, the Germans $42 billion, Britain $28 billion, Italy $9 billion and Japan $6 billion. Japan's GDP is about 7% of the U.S., 14% of Germany's, less than a quarter of Britain's, and less than Italy's.

Yet, most people would agree that Japan was a larger factor in the war than Italy, because the Allies obtained Italy's surrender in September, 1943, and Japan's two years later. And many would agree that Japan's contribution to the war "approximated" (was half or more) of Britain's, and was a decidedly larger fraction of Germany's (one third to one half) than 14%.

For instance, the Japanese army was larger than the British army (and beat equal or larger numbers of Britishers in battles all over Southeast Asia). If you include British "colonial" forces, e.g. Indians and Africans, and Japan's "colonies" in China and Southeast Asia, the numbers of "British" and Japanese population and troops were about the same. The Japanese navy was about the size of the British navy (and actually stronger because of a larger number of modern ships).

Is it reasonable to assume that my linked figures tell the true story, that Japan did the above with "only" one quarter of Britain's GDP? Are there other relative GDP figures that are more reflective of Japan's relative contribution to the war? Or is it more likely that the linked GDP figures for "Japan only" understate Japan's true war potential because the "Japanese Empire" was a lot larger than just Japan? (At its peak, it included half of China, Indochina, Indonesia and the Philippines (basically today's ASEAN countries), Korea, Taiwan and other Pacific countries.)

Comment: What do you call as "contribution to war"? If it is a measure of materiel produced, when you compare Japan vs USA it should be noted that 100 of USAAF heavy bombers (B-17/24/29) would not represent the equivalent of 100 Japanes Zeroes / Kates naval airplanes. Even in a fighter vs fighter comparation you would find USA/UK fighters usually having more complex construction (v.g., self-sealing tanks) than Japan models. Additionally, for most of the war Japan was fighting in a secondary scenario (in 1942, against nations unprepared for war or already commited to the war in Europe).

Comment: Again, (only with the intention of making the question clearer), what would be the formula for "contribution to the war"? Territory controlled? Length of resistence (here Japan would outpeform Germany)? Materiel built? Enemy casualties? Own casualties?

Comment: Wikipedia gives really different GDP estimates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_production_during_World_War_II#GDP). The figures are adjusted for inflation, so only ratios matter. Still, Wiki estimates that Japan had a 1/4 the GDP of the US, larger GDP than Italy, 2/3rds the GDP of Germany, etc. Japan's contribution is much more in proportion according to these figures.

Comment: @twosheds: Kudos to you for finding an alternate, correct source of figures.

Comment: I have narrowed and clarified the question to should we accept the linked GDP figures or are there others that more nearly explain Japan's contribution to the war. I wonder if the question can be reopened in its current form.

Comment: This question is NOT economically accuarate. The quated figures do not appear to be adjusted for PPP (Purchasing Power Parity) and rather are simply converted into USD using an unkown (although hopefully internally consistant) method. When you look at GDP figures, PPP is a critical factor in understanding the true relative strength of economices in terms of their own production.

Comment: I think this is a good question; let's look at how to refine it.  (if only we could use tables).  1) convert GDP to PPP or possibly to a per-capita measure.  2) define "contribution".  2a) Qualitatively, did Japan punch above its weight class? 2b) Qualitatively did Japan outperform Italy? 3) If yes, then how do we quantify & compare contribution to the war? Output of war material? Casualties? 4) Can we measure how much it cost the allies to defeat Italy vice the cost to defeat Japan?

Comment: @StuartAllan: You make a good point. If we can re-open the question, perhaps you would like to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @StuartAllan: That is a good point. The GDP estimates I link to in my answer are displayed in international dollars/[Geary-Khamis dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geary%E2%80%93Khamis_dollar), which are PPP adjusted.

Comment: Italy started the war in June 1940, Japan in December 1941.  So the difference is less - 3 years, 4 months for Italy and 3 years 9 months for Japan.

Comment: @Oldcat: Japan started the war (against China) in 1937, if not 1931. America entered the war against Japan, Germany, and Italy within days of each other. Japan lasted two years longer than Italy at the back end, and three years longer at the front end, five years in all.

Comment: Kicking China's prostrate body hardly is a GDP strain, and was not part of any World War.  Better add in Italy's adventure in Ethiopia, then.

Comment: @Oldcat: According to this source, http://warchronicle.com/numbers/WWII/deaths.htm 10 million Chinese deaths, 5,000 for Ethiopia. Tragic for the latter, but not exactly comparable.

Comment: @T.E.D.: This question has four votes to reopen. Will you be the fifth? It has considerably edited for clarity from its original version, and at least one closer (Mark Wallace) seems to like the current version. Several people seem to have potential answers, based on the comments. –

Comment: I hopefully clarified the question by asking of the "Japanese Empire" was so much larger than "Japan" as to put the country's industrial capacity and GDP in the right "ballpark."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to a [different set of GDP estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_production_during_World_War_II#GDP) (which are [PPP-adjusted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geary%E2%80%93Khamis_dollar) to facilitate cross-national comparisons), Japan's economy is roughly in proportion to @TomAu's estimates of Japan's martial contributions.

For example Tom estimates that Japan contributed more to the war effort than Italy. In every year of the war, Wikipedia estimates that Japan had a larger GDP than Italy. Tom estimates that Japan's contribution was roughly half of Germany's. According to Wikipedia, Japan's GDP was a little under half of Germany's throughout the war. The relative contributions of the Axis powers therefore seem to be fairly proportionate to economic power.

Admittedly, Japan had a much smaller economy than the UK or US. Japan's economy was about a 1/5 of the American economy--but [war needs consumed only a 1/3 of American industrial output](http://prospect.org/article/way-we-won-americas-economic-breakthrough-during-world-war-ii) while Japan devoted [nearly all of its heavy industry to military needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_Japan#20th_century). Divide American GDP by 3 and the number is still larger than Japan's GDP, but by much less. Similarly, the UK's enormous GDP is inflated by the colonies, but these were never going to provide heavy industry comparable to the homeland. Looking at just Britain, the UK's GDP is 50% larger than Japan's. Again, assuming that Japan devoted a larger percentage of its industrial resources to military production than did the UK, then their military contributions are roughly proportionate to their economies.

In this sense, Japan was similar to the USSR, another power that (militarily) punched above its (economic) weight. But it's no secret how the USSR did this: Stalin used the [powers of the state to turn the Soviet economy toward a complete focus on military production](http://stalinsmoustache.org/2012/05/13/stalins-economics-the-secret-to-soviet-success-in-world-war-ii/), uprooting entire industries and hundreds of thousands of workers to Siberia. [Germany didn't even devote its entire industrial output to military production until 1943](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Nazi_Germany#The_war_effort).

In short: Among the Axis powers, Japan's military contribution was roughly proportionate to its economy. The fact that it "outperformed" its economy relative to the Allied powers (other than the USSR) is in part due to the fact that the Japanese government devoted a higher proportion of its economic resources to military production than did the US or UK.

Comment: I would say that Japan outperformed even the figures that you linked. But only to an extent that can be explained by "overachieving." The other interpretation, while extant, isn't plausible.

Comment: @TomAu: Yeah, I agree my answer doesn't explain 100% of the discrepancy. It does make the discrepancy much smaller though, so that strategy/tactics/economic and industrial policy become plausible explanations.

Comment: The reason for the discrepancy is that the bulk of Japan's projectable power was prepaid capital accumulated before the war - their Navy, Carrier Air Arm and Pilots.  Those resource were unrelated to GDP, and once expended in combat were not replacable by any GDP expenditure.  When those were lost in the 42-43 campaigns, the length of the war was only dependent on how long the US would take to recapture the islands Japan had taken, and Japan's GDP was not relevant since they could no longer move produced items to the field, due to the loss of transport.

Comment: @Oldcat: Very interesting comment that would make a good answer. Why don't you vote to reopen (if you haven't already done so) and post this as an answer.

Comment: Canada had a pre-war population of 11,267,000, and fielded 1,029510 effectives in the Royal Canadian Navy, Army, and Air Force combined. This was 9% of the total population and  41% of the male population 18 to 45 years of age (2,474,000). **That's a contribution in excess of GDP.** Link: http://www.canadaatwar.ca/content-7/world-war-ii/facts-and-information/

Comment: As Canada only introduced conscription in November 1944, and only 2,543 of these conscripts actually saw combat before the war ended, you can regard these figures as nearly 100% volunteer. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_Crisis_of_1944

Comment: @TomAu: Canada achieved this despite having a per capita GDP barely over 70% that of either the USA or UK (Page 141 here: https://books.google.ca/books?id=-UPyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA412&lpg=PA412&dq=1938+gdp+for+canada&source=bl&ots=atfFDzD9wJ&sig=0o2v4HIKeVNjADm0wy0RsI0pOyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GTCOVajZK4i1yQT9oYbgAg&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=1938%20gdp%20for%20canada&f=false), in 1938 in 2012 Dollars only 7,114 compared to UK 9,805; US 9,586; and Germany 7,815.

Comment: @TomAu: Discounting *white feather Quebec* where the participation was barely 25%, the rest of Canada **volunteered** 48% of adult males between the ages of 18 and 45 to serve in the Armed Forces during World War ; plus the 12,000 sailors who served in the Merchant Marine keeping Britain afloat through 1940-42.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Those are very good points that are greatly appreciated. That was basically what I was trying to find out (on a per country basis). Will you vote to reopen the question so that you can post your comments as an answer regarding your country, Canada?